# Visual Studio Compiler and recursive Make

Tags: compilation, makefile, cl

I've got a really scary error message while using the visual studio compiler with recursive make.

This is my setup:

Top level Makefile:

```
.PHONY: test

test:
    $(MAKE) -C subdir
```

Makefile in subdir:

```
.PHONY: all

all:
    cl.exe /nologo /c src/interface.cpp
```

The compilation succeeds but I always recieve this warning:

> unrecognized source file type 'cl', object file assumed

This warning only appears when I invoke make using the top level Makfile. If I change the directoy to subdir and run make no error appears.

cl.exe is known to make by running vcvarsall.bat before running make.

I really hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of make are you using?

Comment: Can you show the exact command and output from running the make in the toplevel directory?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I had a variable holding the filename of the compiler and I exported that variable from Make. So the command was cl.exe cl.exe... Thanks!

Comment: There's no variable holding the filename of the compiler in the example makefiles you provided. If you had posted example makefiles that actually reproduced your problem you could have the problem solved long ago.